# Strtok is returning (null) after the first token

Tags: c, strtok

I'm trying to separate a string read from a file by the token '#'. StrTok separates the first token correctly but when i print what is supposed to be the second token it returns nothing but (null).

I tried to change the format of the file that is being read and using an aux variable to hold the content of strtok(NULL,"#"), but the results dont change.

```
void ler_fich_cidades(Lista_Cidades cidade,Lista_Pontos pt){

    FILE *p;
    int file_check=0;
    char linha[TAM];
    Lista_Pontos ptos;
    Cada_cidade city;
    char *aux = (char*)malloc(TAM*sizeof(char));
    p = fopen("locais.txt", "r");


    while(!feof(p)){
        fgetstr(linha,sizeof(linha),p); //this function removes any '\n'.It is working,because it is used for other things

        strcpy(cidade->nome_cidade,strtok(linha,"#")); //This line is working as intended
        printf("%s\n",cidade->nome_cidade);
        strcpy(ptos->ponto.nome,strtok(NULL,"#")); //This one is not


        printf("%s\n",ptos->ponto.nome); //Printing (null)
    }
}
```

The file being read has the following format:

"#Coimbra"
"#Universidade De Coimbra#E uma das universidades mais antigas do mundo ainda em operaçao, sendo a mais antiga e uma das maiores do pais.#8:00h-18:00h#Segunda,Terca,Quarta,Quinta,Sexta,Sábado"

The output is supposed to be:
Coimbra
Universidade De Coimbra

But the actual output is just:
Coimbra

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that strtok is returning NULL. The problem is that you never initialise `ptos`, so it is pointing into limbo.

Also, your function seems to take an argument `pt`, but you never use it.